# Need help, trigger not working right

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger to update another table when a condition is met, however when it's updating it's updating the id field and not the correct field that need updating. Please look at the code and give me an idea what's going on.

In this code the cardinfotable.cardID is the one that been updated.

```
USE [database]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[trgUpdateCard]    Script Date: 2/12/2016 11:05:23 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgUpdateCard] on [dbo].[CardHolderTable] After insert
As
Declare @Counter bigint;
Declare @maxRandomValue bigint = 2000, @minRandomValue bigint = 1000;
begin
Select Cast(((@maxRandomValue + 1) - @minRandomValue) 
    * Rand() + @minRandomValue As bigint) As '@counter'
    update cardinfotable
    Set CardInfoTable.CardNumber = '@Counter' from cardinfotable
    inner join inserted I on I.CardID = CardInfoTable.CardID        
    where I.Visitor = '1'
END
```

Comment: You have your variable wrapped in quotes which makes it a string literal. The bigger problem is that your code assumes there will only ever be a single row in inserted. There can and will (at some point) be multiple rows and your code will be broken. You need to create triggers as set based logic.

Comment: Not sure you're right about the set-based logic this time, @SeanLange.  His code will work for multiple row inserts, it will just update all matches with the same counter value.  That may or may not be desired behavior, no way to know.

Comment: Yes it would execute but I was assuming that he would need unique values for every CardNumber in the CardInfoTable. I can't imagine that is not the case.

Comment: Sean, It's true this have to be unique but between the minimum and the maximum I have a big margin. Those can be deleted in a year or so and there is no stress about it as the program will not accept duplicates but yet will give you a chance to change. The reason I need this is because the number need to be converted to a barcode so the reader will read it

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to populate a variable:

```
Select Cast(((@maxRandomValue + 1) - @minRandomValue) 
    * Rand() + @minRandomValue As bigint) As '@counter'
```

This is the correct way:

```
SET @counter =  Cast(((@maxRandomValue + 1) - @minRandomValue) 
    * Rand() + @minRandomValue As bigint)
```

And then Sean's comment about putting the variable in single-quotes is correct.  If you want to actually use the value in the variable, you need to remove the quotes.

Also, you need to move the `BEGIN` statement to before your `DECLARE` statements:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgUpdateCard] on [dbo].[CardHolderTable] After insert
As
begin

Declare @Counter bigint;
Declare @maxRandomValue bigint = 2000, @minRandomValue bigint = 1000;
...
```

Comment: It's not working, I am getting the result as I have no trigger, here is what the trigger looks like after your suggestion

Comment: are you sure you insert rows with *Visitor = '1'* and corresponding row in CardInfoTable exists?

Comment: Yes, when the program inserts. It does that into 2 tables with the cardid is the same. There are 2 types of cards that is inserted, regular employee card and a visitor card, I cannot manipulate the employee card however I need to change the visitor card. It's either changing the cardid value to the random number generated or it does not change the number.

Comment: I don't see where you've shown what the trigger looks like after implementing my suggestions.   Can you edit your question to show the new code?